# Stepping Thread Group does not ramp down

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using STG with OS Process sampler executing a shell script which does some operations in a loop.
The Ramp up and steady stage works well.

However the Ramp Down does not happen as expected. The threads/shell scripts keep on executing even after the time period has expired.

The setup is in distributed mode.
and JMeter Logs are showing: "Sampler is not Interruptible"

Please suggest

Regards